# Firebase is sending an Reset Password email after create a new user in the backend side

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I need to create new users in Next.js project with a temporary password.
The user is created in an Next API route to create a new account.
After created, the program sends a welcome email to the new user with the temporary password.

The problem is that Firebase is sending another email that I don't know where and why. The user is receiving two emails. My custom email and one from Firebase.

This is the email that Firebase is sending by error. As you can see, the subject is "Cuenta Creada", but Firebase has no an Account Created template, but the content is from Reset Password template.

[image: Email content]

This is the code related to the user creation:

```js
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
//...
//...
const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, idTeamLead } = req.body;
const fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
const password = generatePassword();
if (!firstName || !lastName || !email) {
  return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Missing fields' });
}
let user = null;
try {
  user = await auth.createUser({
    email: email,
    emailVerified: false,
    password: password,
    displayName: fullName,
    disabled: false,
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  return res.status(400).json(error);
}
```

- Next.js version:12.1.4
- node version:16.14.2
- firebase:^9.6.8
- firebase-admin version:^10.2.0

The project is deployed in Vercel Platform but it ocurres both, local and production environments.

Comment: *firebaser here* I checked with some of our engineers and we't find a way how you could trigger this in our backend flow. The template you shared also looks different, as our default shows an email link rather than the button you have. Are you sure this email can't have been copy/pasted from the console and then actually be coming from your own pipeline?

Comment: It's really weird. I am sending just one email after the code above, receiving it without problems. I look for that template in FIrebase Console, but the only one similar is the reset password template, but it has a different subject text. 

And I am receiving two emails: the correct one and the wrong one.

Comment: Yeah, definitely weird. The fact that the email looks slightly different from the template is also why I can't imagine it coming from our pipeline though. For us to send a password reset email, the request has to come from the client-side SDK (or REST API) by the account itself (to prevent it being used to spam users).

Comment: Recently I found I am trying to reset the password manually in the code. 
```
await auth.updateUser(uid, { password: newPassword });
```
This works, but it seems to be causing this weird email, and still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the user's password (or their email address for that matter) from the client-side SDK sends an email the (current/previous) email address of that user, as it is a common abuse angle. So that code definitely explains why the user is getting an email message from Firebase about your app.

I'm still investigating why the email's subject is off.